# Space getting added between characters while writing to PDF using binary write

Tags: vb.net, pdf

Here is issue screenshot

[image: Here is issue screenshot]

Here is the sample code.

```
Dim rawData As Byte() = "sample data"
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
Response.ContentEncoding =  System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
Response.BinaryWrite(rawData)
Response.End()
```

Comment: *"Space getting added between characters while writing to PDF using binary write"* - but you are not writing to pdf, you are writing a simple text and *claim* in the response headers that it is a pdf. That claim alone doesn't make it a pdf, though...

Comment: @mkl does it make change with contentEncoding ?

Comment: No. Pdf content requires a specific binary format which does not simply turn up by claiming it's there. You need to explicitly have to create pdf data. Look for pdf libraries for your environment. You can find some that have explicit ways to add table or paragraph structures to the pdf, and some that create content by conversion from e.g. html. The output of these libraries is a binary in pdf format.

Comment: This is VB.NET and won't compile in the first place. Strings aren't byte arrays and can't be assigned to a `Byte()` variable. This code throws `BC30311 Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to 'Byte()'.`. In any case, the code doesn't create a PDF file, it tries to send some text to the browser with a fake content type.

Answer (score 3):

> Space getting added between characters while writing to PDF using binary write

The underlying issue here is that you actually are *not writing a PDF at all!*

Your code essentially returns pure text data and then *claims* that it is a PDF. Such a claim doesn't change the text data in any way, though, they remain text and don't become a PDF.

The PDF viewer you use apparently attempts to somehow display what it got nonetheless but the result thereof turns out to be very unsatisfying (a proportional font seems to be used in a monospaced manner).

If you actually want to return a PDF, you have to explicitly create one. PDF is a complicated binary format best to create using a dedicated library.

Look for pdf libraries for your environment. You can find some that have explicit ways to add table or paragraph structures to the pdf, and some that create content by conversion from another structured format e.g. html.

The output of these libraries is a binary in pdf format which you can return from your code using `Response.BinaryWrite`.

---

Recently one can read in a number of questions that people have data in text or html format, return it setting some binary content type (PDF in this question, MS office formats in other ones), and then assume they so have generated a file in that format.

*This is wrong, claiming a format doesn't transform into that format!*

All this setting of the content type does, is informing the client what kind of viewer to use to open the data.

Probably this anti-pattern came up because MS Word (and most likely other word processors, too) can also open plain text and html text files and display them fairly properly. Thus, this anti-pattern at first glance *appears* to work somehow.

If you promised your client, though, that your application returns MS Office documents, **don't return HTML or plain text claiming it to be an Office document, instead do create actual MS Office documents!** Otherwise knowledgeable clients will not accept your implementation and clients who did accept it will eventually be informed by knowledgeable users that you cheated them which will at least lessen your renown.

Comment: Reminds me of renaming a .bmp to .jpg and "proving" that, given Paint could still open the file, I had changed the format of the file. In my defense, I was like 10 years old at the moment.

Comment: @CodeCaster imagine having some partner in an EEC-funded project deliver format conversion code that simply changed the header bytes in a picture

Comment: @CodeCaster Yes, essentially the same, merely here one could theoretically blindly assume that the `ContentType` property triggers a universal conversion machine... very blindly...